# Selecting few arrays from a list and displaying their content

Tags: list-manipulation, feyncalc

I am using `FeynHiggs` package on Mathematica 11 to calculate fermion masses in MSSM. Function `FHGetPara[]` returns a list that looks something like this-

```
 {MSf[1, 1] -> {1645.58, 1.*10^123}, USf[1, 1] -> {{1., 0}, {0, 1.}}, 
  MSf[1, 2] -> {1645.58, 1.*10^123}, USf[1, 2] -> {{1., 0}, {0, 1.}}, 
  MSf[1, 3] -> {1645.58, 1.*10^123}, USf[1, 3] -> {{1., 0}, {0, 1.}}, 
  MSf[2, 1] -> {1647.37, 1647.5}, 
  USf[2, 1] -> {{0.0120161, 0.999928}, {0.999928, -0.0120161}}, 
  MSf[2, 2] -> {1647.09, 1647.77}, 
  USf[2, 2] -> {{0.633543, 0.773708}, {0.773708, -0.633543}}, 
  MSf[2, 3] -> {1641.82, 1653.03}, 
  USf[2, 3] -> {{0.702865, 0.711323}, {0.711323, -0.702865}}, 
  MASf[2] -> {1647.37, 1647.09, 1641.82, 1647.5, 1647.77, 1653.03}...}
```

I want to select only `MSf` elements. I tried using

```
 msf=MSf/.FHGetPara[];
 msf[1,1]
```

But It is not giving any result. What should I do?

Comment: Try `Cases[FHGetPara[], HoldPattern[MSf[__] -> _]]` and report back.

Comment: It returns me all `MSf`  arrays. What if I want a particular element of a particular `MSf` array?

Comment: Then you use `MSf[1, 1] /. (* list of rules *)`.